# C++ Programming on a Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-construction, netbeans

I have installed Xcode 4.0 (XCode Toolset, System Tools and Documentation components only), but have Netbeans with the C/C++ plugin. However when I try to create a new C++ project in Netbeans it tells me that no compiler was found on my system. The recommended course of action is to install Xcode, which I have done so.

How do I get Netbeans to recognize that I already have Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you reinstall Xcode and this time *don't* uncheck the option that installs the compiler, etc. under `/usr/bin` for command line use. What's wrong with just having a full installation of Xcode?

If that doesn't work, it may be an incompatibility due to Xcode 4 installing to `/Xcode4` instead of `/Developer`. You can fix that with a symlink or by installing Xcode 3.